# Change column width irrespective of its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I want to dynamically collapse table column to specific width (10 px in this case) whenever user clicks on column header. It will be good if we can keep the cells height fixed while changing the column width.
For example table will be displayed like:
[image]
When user clicks on column header (red minus button here), column should shrink and should look like:
[image]
Here in example given in jsFiddle column shrinks to fixed width and height remains same.

Here is what I have tried till now [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/DJ3Yk/#base).

I have used:

```
  table-layout:fixed;
  word-wrap:break-word;
```

but column shrinks to the width same as first word. It don't break the work to make width `10px`.
Here column width shrinks to adapt word `Lonnnnng`.

**It will be great if we get any plugin like datatable which allows this feature** (i.e. dynamic collapse and expansion of columns to a particular width). There are many plugin which allows user to hide particular column but I want to shrink it instead of hiding.

---

**EDIT :**

After trying few suggestions I realize that a **plugin will be better solution** for this as I have to look after all browser and resolution supports.Doing all this stuff through written code will be the last thing I will do [I have to do :D ].Do we have any plugin which provides such feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part missing from your solution is setting the table width. Once the table width is fixed (e.g. set to `100%`) the column width becomes fixed as well. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9QkVd/1/

My example code also toggles the `collapsed` class instead of manipulating CSS values directly, this is a more reliable approach. And the same class is set for all other cells in the column to allow applying `text-overflow: ellipsis` there as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer.Just wondering if we can keep the height intact while changing width.It looks like your (you gave great way to apply class to all cells in column) and Tim's answer (applying css to div instead of td) together will satisfy all my needs.

Comment: @Ajinkya: You could probably go with `white-space: nowrap` CSS property for the `collapsed` class.

Comment: Just observed if you try to collapse all columns something goes wrong. Can you please check it ? Till then I will try to find out whats going wrong.

Comment: @Ajinkya: Well, table width is 100%, it needs to show *something*. I guess that you want to change table width if all columns are collapsed. See http://jsfiddle.net/9QkVd/2/ - here I add `collapsed` class for the table if that happens, `width: 0px;` then means that the table width is the sum of column widths.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jY7mb/1/

I wrapped the content of each cell in a `div`, and I adjust the width of the div instead of the width of the column.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I am looking for.Will try to avoid overhead of adding class to each td and instead will prefer Wladmirs part of solution to do the same.

Comment: OK. Didn't know about the `cellIndex` property. You can use the jQuery `:nth-child` selector to get the correct cell in each row, instead of the class name.

Comment: Thanks Tim, your solution works like a charm. Was confused to whom should I give the bounty. Selected Wladimir for his fast and clean approach. Still thanks a lot. +1 :D

Comment: Damn! :) (Hint: Wladimir's doesn't work because the table width is set to 100%)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution: http://cssdesk.com/xvpR2

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Tried but no luck http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/DJ3Yk/11/

Comment: For your suggestion to work text need to inside `<div>` only, the css you used do not work when applied to `<td>`. As my table is dynamically created it is not possible to place each content inside `<div>` .

Comment: Wouldn't that also mean you could dynamically create divs? Haven't used it myself, but I think wrapInner could do the trick: http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

Comment: Will keep it as last option as I have to wrap every cell in particular column whenever user clicks on particular column header.
+ 1 for wrapInner :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/DJ3Yk/14/ Just need to apply same class for all `td` in same column. Thanks
Waiting for other answers.